# How realistic is beating facial recognition?

Tags: realism, prison-break

In Prison Break season 5 Michael Scofield prints Jacob's face on his hand to beat facial recognition system to access his office.

[image: Michael printed Jacob's face.]

Wouldn't it be easy to fool system with printing on paper or 3-D cast ? And. .

How realistic is Michael's method ?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the facial recognition system and how well-programmed it is.

Comment: @F1Krazy agreed as people are beating iPhone X face recognition by many methods lately, same can be achieved for other face detentions too

Comment: I'm not sure about the application in this episode (I would think the lines caused by his fingers would mess up the effort), but *in general* if the facial recognition system only has one camera lens, then it can't use stereoscopics (ie; it can't see the third dimension, so an image of the person's face - with sufficient resolution - would be indistinguishable from the actual person's face.)

Comment: @AnkitSharma beating iphone's face recognition is easy. I think jacob could've used more advanced piece of technology in here

Comment: @Vishwa depends on requirement.

Comment: It depends. Maybe he used hands because of some sensors which check if it is heat radiated from skin or not.

Comment: Seeing as how the capabilities of facial recognition are probably hugely exaggerated on the show, I'm not sure how one can determine the realism of defeating exaggerated technology.

Answer (score 7):

Before Answering the question let me give a small outline .

Face Recognition works different in different applications . 
Lets take smart phones ,

Early in 2011-13 , when Andriod introduced Face Recognition for lockscreen in Andriod 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) it could be fooled by a Photo but not with another face . So at this stage it can differentiate between faces but not the real and fake (3d and 2d object). This is a **Problem**.

Now Iphone X has this Face ID thing , which can recognise whether you have the attention (eyes on phone). It cannot be fooled with a photo (2d) . It certainly differentiates between a 2d and 3d object . That **Problem** is no more an issue . But even with this case there are 3d printed photos ( Masks to be precise ) , which are claimed to fool the Iphone x too . [Claiming to Fool Iphone X](https://www.wired.com/story/hackers-say-broke-face-id-security/)

Samsung has IRIS scanner people claim even it can be fooled, I think pairing this with face recognition may increase it's security .

Now coming to answer , (I Dont remember episode exactly just watched that part now)

Because Face Recognition only depends on the face and not the tiny details like breathing or blinking the eye , It can always be fooled either by a 3d mask or who knows Skin mask with a actual hair wig and colors which match 100% .

To anyone who is reading this working on a Face Recognition tech , I would love you to associate Face Recogntion with face gestures . Like when i look at the screen and blink my eyes .

So somewhere in future we may have Technology which even over comes this problem .